# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ represent the integers and the rationals, respectively.
>
> `(a)` Prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I am stuck on this topology problem from my homework, if anyone would be of some help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: what is its complement in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at $(n,n+1)$ it is open in $\mathbb R$ for any $n\in\mathbb Z$, hence $U=\cup _{n\in\mathbb Z}(n,n+1)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ (any union of open sets is open) thus $\mathbb R\setminus U$ is close in $\mathbb R$  (a compliment of an open set is a close set) but $\mathbb R\setminus U=\mathbb Z$ thus $\mathbb Z$ is a close set in $\mathbb R$